# Using this keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Mongoose Schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
  password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Above code is just to show UserSchema is just an instance. I'm confused when `this` is used below. What does that refer to?

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically:

```
var user = this;
```

Refers to:

```
UserSchema
```

Console log it:

```
var user = this;
console.log(user);
```

And take a look around!

> Why do we even need to create an instance? – @Nichole A. Miler

It gives you options to create more than one instance.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({...});
var AnotherUserSchema = new Schema({...});
```

Comment: What is the advantage of writing it that way? I rarely see this kind of approach. Why do we even need to create an instance?

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword into a pre save middleware refers to an User Document that you are about to save, in this case within name and password if those are already set. 
Plus, every mongoose/mongo benefits, methods like, isNew, isModified, also virtual fields and methods in your schema, etc

Answer (score 0):

I think that's one of the most confused mechanisms in ECMAScript. When you say "this", I think it creates confusion because we try to think about it too *literally* and one of the most common misconceptions about it is that, somehow, it refers to the function's scope — let me make it clear here: `this` does not refer to a function's lexical scope...at all.

`this`, in ECMAScript, it's "contextual based" on the conditions of the function's invocation. `this` binding has nothing to do with where a function is declared, but has instead everything to do with the manner in which the function is called. So a nice way to start is what `this` is not.

In your case, you want to "keep the context" because it will be referred later on, and as soon as your other function is invoked, an activation record, otherwise known as an execution context, is created...and eventually, if you need to refer to the previous one, you won't have it.

Play with `console.log()` and see what you have in every call, that can give you a clue.

**NOTE:** ECMAScript 6 has some "improvements" about/on this :)